# what is the difference between wp-admin & wp-admin.php?

Tags: wordpress

When we go to the admin login page of Wordpress, we type "somedomain.com/wp-admin" and it redirects us to "somedomain.com/wp-admin.php".

What is the difference between wp-admin & wp-admin.php?

Comment: There is not difference, it just wordpress removing the php with apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just redirecting you to the `.php` file which is the file that contains the code for your login page.

**PS**

When using wordpress you should have your `wp-admin` in another folder like this

`www.mysite.com/strange/wp-admin`

Because there is a lot of bots out there that crawl the web looking for the wp-admin page on your domain and they usually look for it right after the domain, and once they get that page they will start trying to hack your login and with WP the login isn't very secure it's actually fairly easy to get into a wordpress sites admin panel, any ways hope that help!